# Calculating Resistor Value in Boiler Power Pump Module

Tags: circuit-analysis, resistors

My home boiler stopped working a few hours after turning it on for the start of the heating season.  I found 2 damaged resistors (R7 & R8) in the power pump module.  The markings on the resistors are not visible.  Section of the circuit shown below.  How can I determine the value of the damaged resistors?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwnRPz.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

What would cause the resistors to fail?  Is the transformer the most likely cause?  I measured 27V AC output voltage (no load).  The windings measure 46 ohms (primary) and 2.5 ohms (secondary).  Could the transformer create a fault only when under load?  Are there any other tests I should perform on the transformer to help confirm its condition?  Should I replace the transformer in addition to R7 & R8?

Throughout the module resistors are in pairs in parallel.  Why would this be done, rather than using a single resistor of equivalent resistance?

Thanks for your help.